# Do aggregation queries have high tail latencies, and if so why?

Tags: sql, database

I was watching a video on SQL databases that said that aggregation queries can often have very high tail latencies (>p90). The particular query referenced was a sum. I'm not sure why that would be the case? How is summing a bunch of rows much worse than returning a bunch of rows, isn't addition extremely fast?

Or is this just a wrong statement?

Comment: If you have to read every row in a table and perform an operation on it, it will take O(n) time.  This is different then an index operation that takes O(log n).

Comment: Which dbms is the video covering?

Comment: I'd say GROUP BY queries _can_ be expensive. They can also be very fast.